# Convert -append *Grid

Tags: linux, image, bash, imagemagick

How can I set grid for "convert" command?
I want to create a sprite with 10x10 grid.
The following command creates 1x100

```
convert -quality 60 $files -append $filename
```

what else i've tried

```
montage $files -tile 10x10 $filename
montage $files -tile 10x10 -geometry 110x60+0+0 -quality 60 $filename
```

the above two  created 100x1

Answer (score 2):

The `-append` option stacks images vertically.

Use the `+append` option to stack images horizontally.

`montage` utility that is also a part of `ImageMagick` provides a `-tile` option that would likely make your task easier (by specifying `-tile 10x10` although you can work around using `convert`).

Comment: the following just created 100x1 `                montage $files -tile 10x10 $filename
`